# Is there a way to create javascript prototype from json?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, code-generation

I have some webapi than expose successfull JSON well formed response.

I have found more and more code for use that services from javascript and return a generic json object.

I would like convert that json object to javascript prototyped object and before of that, i would like to create (one time) prototype code directly from JSON response.

So, there is any way to achive this target?

(I have server side .net objects and access to that code, but i wouln't use time to write DTO objects manually).

The single Json isn't so relevant, but for example:

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

I would like to generate it's prototype, something as

```
function menu() {
    this.id= '';
    this.value= '';
    this.popup= '';

    this.menuitem = function ()
    {
        value = null;
        onclick = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: read teh string, build a  text string of the javascript you want, and then "eval" that.

Comment: There is no built-in support of JSON-to-specifc-prototype deserialization. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/185429/1625737

Comment: Unlikely. Object prototypes often have methods (for example) and you can't really represent those easily in JSON format.

Comment: I understand than i can create only the "first use" code, after that i'll add client code as needed. I've found something to convert json to java, i need something similar.  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/